# Implement CLS to BIOS INT10

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bios

Recently switched to 25x80 screen mode but cursor is not present using:

```
MOV AX,01111
MOV BL,0
INT 010
```

question is how do I call bios for a clearscreen??

I checked Ralf Brown's interrupt list for Int x10 at:

```
http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-10.htm
```

[ralf link](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-10.htm)

and found AH=06 and AH=07 to be:

```
Int 10/AH=06h - VIDEO - SCROLL UP WINDOW
Int 10/AH=07h - VIDEO - SCROLL DOWN WINDOW
```

Comment: Show your whole program. However i doubt that is it written for qbasic

Comment: Try function 06h or 07h of int 10h

Comment: In Ralf Brown's interrupt list AX=06 and AX=07 INT10 scrolls windows but is not a clearscreen.

Comment: It is AH=06h and AL is set to zero to clear the entire screen as written in Ralf Brown's interrupt list

Comment: @Lee - the assembly you see above is the whole program..

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [How can I clear the screen without having to fill it](//stackoverflow.com/q/8239143)?  Or [Can't clear entire screen in 16-bit real mode Assembly](//stackoverflow.com/q/22972951)?

Comment: That does answer my question.. And thanks to Lee for the correct comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is: (a duplicate);

```
clearScreen:
pusha

mov ax, 0x0700  ; function 07, AL=0 means scroll whole window
mov bh, 0x07    ; character attribute = white on black
mov cx, 0x0000  ; row = 0, col = 0
mov dx, 0x184f  ; row = 24 (0x18), col = 79 (0x4f)
int 0x10        ; call BIOS video interrupt

popa
ret
```

Copied from Edward at [edward post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22972951/cant-clear-entire-screen-in-16-bit-real-mode-assembly)

Comment: Copied without attribution (aka [plagiarized](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268629/how-do-we-deal-with-plagiarized-answers)) from @Edward's answer on [Can't clear entire screen in 16-bit real mode Assembly](//stackoverflow.com/q/22972951).  When you find the answer to your question on another SO question, close it as a duplicate instead of copying the answer.  (Unless the answer is long and covers lots of other things.  That's not the case here.)

Comment: Sorry, I thought once it was posted it became public domain..

Comment: That is, who owns the copyright to a post?

Comment: The poster owns their post; posting it on SO publishes it under the CC-by-SA license, allowing others to copy it *with attribution*.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing.  Also, plagiarism is a separate problem from violating copyright.  e.g. if I post one of Shakespeare's sonnets somewhere under my own name, without saying I didn't write it, I haven't violated copyright (the work is public domain) but anyone who's impressed by "my" post shouldn't be giving me credit for it.

Comment: I must give **appropriate credit** to any copied text or programs then?

Comment: Yes.  Or in this case, instead of duplicating information, Stack Overflow has a mechanism to point one question at another as a duplicate.  That's why I asked in comments if this question was a duplicate of those others, so we could close this as a duplicate, not so someone could copy the answer.  [How should duplicate questions be handled?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841)

Comment: You might as well just delete this answer; it's a straight copy of another.  Future readers should follow the duplicate and read that answer (in case it gets updated), not this copy.  That's why Stack Overflow supports duplicate links.